# Excel UserForm size related to screen scaling

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Is there any way to scale UserForm according to screen scaling?

[image]

This code works for screen resolution, but it does not recognize screen scaling:

```
With Me
   .StartUpPosition = 1
   .Width = Application.Width * 0.85
   .Height = Application.Height * 0.85
   .Left = Application.Left + (Application.Width * 0.85) \ 2
   .Top = Application.Top + (Application.Height * 0.85) \ 2
End With
```